Is there an iterator in Python that gives the product but omits permutations of the classes itself?
Assume that I want to assign a color to 5 different balls and have 3 colors r,b and g. I would like to iterate over all these combinations. Preferably I would want to omit combinations that are equal up to permutation of the color classes. That means for example that I want to consider (r,b,b,b,b) and (g,r,r,r,r) as equal.
I could use
itertools.product('rbg', repeat=5)

but this would overcount by a lot. Maybe
itertools.combinations_with_replacement('rbg', 5)

would be better? I am not sure if this approach would not miss some. But it would certainly see (r,b,b,b,b) and (g,r,r,r,r) as different combinations. Is there anything better I could do?

These are integer partitions up to a size equal to your number of colors.

I should have emphasized that the balls are distinguishable. So (r,b,b,b,b) and (b,b,b,b,r) should not be in the same equivalence class. If I am not mistaken, integer partitions would not consider this.

combinations_with_replacement would consider those equivalent.

Your sizes are small enough to filter the product, and I think this does what you mean:
from itertools import product

for p in product('rbg', repeat=5):
    f = ''.join(p).find
    if f('r') <= f('b') <= f('g'):
        print(p)

The idea is to normalize by order of first appearance. To ignore the six permutations of the three colors, I picked one: check that the first appearing color is r (or it doesn't appear), the second is b, and the third is g.
Output (Attempt This Online!):
('r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'g')
('r', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'g')
('r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'g')
('r', 'r', 'b', 'g', 'r')
('r', 'r', 'b', 'g', 'b')
('r', 'r', 'b', 'g', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'r')
('r', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'b')
('r', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'r')
('r', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'b')
('r', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'r')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'b')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'r')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'b')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'g')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'r')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'b')
('r', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'g')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'g')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'g')
('b', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'g', 'b', 'g')
('b', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'b')
('b', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'g')
('b', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'g')
('b', 'g', 'b', 'g', 'b')
('b', 'g', 'b', 'g', 'g')
('b', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'b')
('b', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'g')
('b', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b')
('b', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g')
('g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g')


Maybe some explanation for why / how this would be working?

@Julien Ok I added a bit. Not sure it's clear, it's almost 5 AM and I'm sleepy :-)

Awesome, thanks! This seems correct to me. It at least passes my sanity test of expecting 41 combinations.

it works ;) as expected
